# What does the world think about the death of Gadafi?

Tags: libya

After the death of Gadafi, I didn't hear much more about it -- what does the world think about the death of Gadafi?

Comment: This question is on hold because it is too broad. But it is a good question and should be saved by restricting to the title question (the other aspects could give interesting questions too)

Comment: could it be narrowed down to, _"How has the death of Qaddafi affected corporations and governments"_ would that be less broad?

Comment: "The World" is seven billion people, each one with their own unique thoughts. In order to make this question answerable you have to limit it to the thoughts of people you are interested in specifically and who are important enough to have their thoughts published.

Comment: You could start by asking if the world population (strongly/mildly) approves, disapproves, does not care or does not know. Asking for every thought on the topic is what makes it too broad. Also note that there may be some places far away from Libya where no data is available (a pointer to a general "do not care")

Answer (score 1):

AlJazeera and PBS have a few articles on it ([1](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/africa/2011/10/20111020111520869621.html) [2](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/frontline/article/regrets-of-a-revolution-libya-after-qaddafi/) [3](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/africa/2011/10/20111020161338365577.html)). They seem to be mostly positive on the death of Qaddafi except for one, a few quotes:

> *"Thank God they have caught this person"* a fighter said.
>
> *"For the region, today's events prove once more that the rule of an iron fist inevitably comes to an end."* - Barack Obama
>
> *"However, life for the average Libyan today, in some ways, has become more dangerous and unstable than it was under Qaddafi, according to experts."* - PBS Frontline

## Conclusion

So it seems that while the death of Qaddafi was welcome, the actual ability of the government ts control the militia groups and other military organizations had gone down. Now the country is ruled by fear of death from the militia groups fighting for power rather than a stable government. One person even saying that they preffered the stability of Qaddafi's rule:

> “You could walk down the streets at night under Qaddafi, but it was the peace of the graveyard”

Comment: I think I remember that quote about the graveyard.

Comment: "Peace of the graveyard" passage in the last quote seems to imply that the speaker prefers current state of the country as opposed to Qaddafi's, no?

Comment: It does seem to imply security or stability without justice or vitality, possibly a resigned or fearful population, or suppression of large segments of the population by a fearful government.  The quote sounds lucid but without context it could mean just about anything.

Comment: in the article it says that they preffered rule under Qaddafi

Comment: That sounds like the graveyard at least was outside the home, maybe.  I'm all over the place thinking about it, though I have no illusions my country cared what happened to most of the people.  With so much pressure on countries with desired resources I don't know how any of them survive.